# What is a good mouse to use with a standing desk?

Tags: mice, ergonomics

Since I have my standing desk, I wonder what the best mouse type is to use while working standing.

I mostly use a vertical mouse but I am starting to doubt it now as you can't lean your elbow. That's why I was thinking of getting a trackball mouse (don't mind a good investment if it benefits my health) or maybe just a regular mouse.

What would be the best from an ergonomic point of view? (to reduce/avoid RSI)

Thank you

Comment: Hi Piet, what's your budget? Are there any specific features you need (e.g., macro buttons or scroll wheel type)?

Comment: Hey @Adam , I don't want to limit my budget to much, so I would go until a bit over a 100 euro. I don't have any specific features in mind, I'm just curious to find out what would type of mouse would work best in an ergonomic sense for a standing desk work set-up.

Comment: All I would mention is that I've used a very ordinary Logitech trackball for many years and have had no trouble with RSI. *However*, I do have some discomfort, at cooler times of year with circulation to my right hand, apparently owing to the fact that the desk surface is higher than my right elbow. The hand becomes uncomfortably cold after lengthy periods of work. I sometimes resort to placing the trackball in my lap.

Answer (score 1):

To be completely honest with you, as long as you have a suitable surface to use the mouse on any mouse will work.

When it comes to ergonomics, there are extended armrests that can attach to a desk....[example](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00LW5TBV6)

Personally I have been using a MadCatz/Cyborg R.A.T.7 for since 2010, just replaced it with a new one after 6 years due to it dying after heavy use.
I use the older version[RAT 7](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0095D1CM8)

It is a gaming mouse, but is can be customized, and you can add/remove weights, which for me helps deal with muscle twitches in my hands/wrists due to too many years on ADHD/Aspergers medications.

Have had no issue with RSI/RMI with this mouse.

Comment: Alright! I think the extended armrest would be a good idea! and maybe I get a trackball too to have some variation. Thanks!